# Can we get date and timestamp by only using moment-timezone.js in angular 2 or higher

Tags: angular, timezone, momentjs

My code is like this

```js
time = moment().format('LTS');
date = moment().format('LL');
timezone = moment.tz.guess();
```

can I achieve same without using moment.js if I only use moment-timezone.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment-Timezone is an add-on library to Moment.js, so No, you cannot use it alone.

In your code above, Moment is providing the functionality for the first two lines.  The third line is provided by moment-timezone.

If all you need is the third line, you can get similar functionality from [jsTimeZoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect), but if you're already using Moment then you might as well take it from Moment-Timezone.